# Why cant i find this tag in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im new to python, or any comp language for that matter, but im trying to scrape a title from a site using this code, but it keeps printing "None" as if the title, or any tag if i replace it, doesn't exists.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = "https://www.roblox.com/catalog/?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=the%20item&SortAggregation=5&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

ttt = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"CatalogItemName notranslate"})
item = ttt.a.text
print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content that you are looking for is not in the http response recieved from the server. It is generated by javascript once the page have loaded.

When doing crawling tasks, you should always load the websites on your browser without javascript to get a better idea of what the raw html content looks like.

Finally, you can solve this by using a crawler with javascript support like selenium.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find element using multiple classes,I think following is the convention.

```
soup.find("div", {'class':['CatalogItemName', 'notranslate']})
```